# How to load big scene from server in swift

Tags: scnscene

I put art.scnassets in my local server and tried to use SCNScene(url: options:) to load the .scn 
The assets are from fox2 Apple sample code.

Turns out: model is loaded successful but maps cannot be found, and options like "assetDirectoryUrls" did not help.

Any clue would be appreciated!